# How do I implement DeviceSource for streaming from webcam in Live555?

Tags: c++, stream, streaming, video-streaming, live555

I am working on a webcam streaming server project, using **Live555** as the server.
I need to be able to stream from **ordinary USB Webcams**, which requires me to implement **DeviceSource.cpp** as I read on live555's FAQ page. However, I am currently not having enough knowledge or clue on how to implement this.

I intend to use **ffmpeg** as the encoder.

Can anybody provide me with some proper directions that I can follow?